# How did Lot become so rich?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-lech-lecha

We are told in Bereshit 13:5-6 (Sefaria translation) :

> "Lot, who went with Abram, also had flocks and herds and tents..."
>
> "..so that the land could not support them staying together; for their possessions were so great that they could not remain together."

How did Lot get so wealthy? Do we know what happened to him in Egypt, assuming he went down there with Abram and Sarai?

Comment: Perhaps elaborate a little more on your question; I quibble with that last part "assuming he went down there with Abram and Sarai?" - do you have sources that indicate otherwise? _Rashi_ quotes _Medrash Rabbah_  that attributes Lot's good fortune to his proximity to Abraham.

Comment: We are not explicitly told by the text that Lot went DOWN with them to Egypt, however the Torah says quite explicitly he went back UP to Eretz Canaan with Abram and Sarai. Consequently, if he went back up with them you would think he was with them in Egypt but the Torah is silent about it. Why? Did he get rich in the meanwhile?

Comment: I always assumed from the juxtaposition of the verses, that Lot was also enriched by the Egyptians since he was with Avram.

Comment: How about the idea that Lot became rich because through inheritance? His two sisters did not inherit when Haran died. So everything because Lot's, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [classic Meforshi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.13.5?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=en)m do not explain where the wealth came from - and none of them claim it came from the Egyptians.

The all say that **Lot became wealthy in Avraham's merit**. E.g. [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.13.5?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.13.5.1&lang2=bi):

> ההלך את אברם. מִי גָרַם שֶׁהָיָה לוֹ זֹאת? הֲלִיכָתוֹ עִם אַבְרָם:‏
>
> WHO WENT WITH ABRAM — What brought it about that he possessed all this? The fact that he was accompanying Abram (Genesis Rabbah 41:3; Pesikta Rabbati, שמיני).

This [and other sources] make it sound like it was a Gcd -given reward for hanging around a Tzadik.

Their source is probably [Bava Kama 93a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Kamma.93a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that says:

> א"ל רבא לרבה בר מרי מנא הא מילתא דאמרי אינשי בתר מרי ניכסי ציבי משך א"ל דכתיב (בראשית יג, ה) **וגם ללוט ההולך את אברם** היה צאן ובקר ואהלים‏
>
> Rava said to Rabba bar Mari: From where is this matter derived whereby people say: Drag wood after a property owner. In other words, help out a wealthy man even in a small way, as this may lead to your benefiting from him. Rabba bar Mari said to him that the source is as it is written: “**And Lot also, who went with Abram**, had flocks, and herds, and tents” (Genesis 13:5).

This makes it sounds like it's a natural cause; hand around the rich and you'll probably get rich.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned **Lot became rich by virtue of his proximity to Avraham**. There are many sources that bring this idea out.

[Eicha Rabbah 1:38](https://www.sefaria.org/Eichah_Rabbah.1.38?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> **אַרְבָּעָה דְּבָרִים טוֹבִים הֵיטִיב אַבְרָהָם לְלוֹט**, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב (בראשית יב, ד): וַיֵּלֶךְ אַבְרָם כַּאֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר אֵלָיו ה' וַיֵּלֶךְ אִתּוֹ לוֹט. וְאוֹמֵר **(בראשית יג, ה): וְגַם לְלוֹט הַהֹלֵךְ אֶת אַבְרָם וגו'.** וְאוֹמֵר (בראשית יד, טז): וַיָּשֶׁב אֵת כָּל הָרְכֻשׁ וגו'. וְאוֹמֵר (בראשית יט, כט): וַיְהִי בְּשַׁחֵת אֱלֹהִים אֶת עָרֵי הַכִּכָּר וגו'.
>
> **Four good things Avraham caused to make good for Lot** like it writes: ([Bereishis 12:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.4?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) "And Avram went when Hashem spoke to him, and Lot went with him". And it says **([Bereishis 13:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.13.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) "Lot, who went with Abram, (also had flocks and herds and tents)"**. And it says ([Bereishis 14:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.14.16?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) "He brought back all the possessions; (he also brought back his kinsman Lot and his possessions, and the women and the rest of the people)". And it says ([Bereishis 19:29](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), "And it was that, when G-d destroyed the cities of the Plain (and annihilated the cities where Lot dwelt, G-d was mindful of Abraham and removed Lot from the midst of the upheaval)".

The [Midrash Lekach Tov](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Lekach_Tov%2C_Genesis.13.5.1?lang=bi) adds:

> לא דיין לצדיקים שזוכין לעצמן אלא שמזכין גם לאחרים הנדבקין עמהם
>
> It is not enough for the righteous to merit for themselves but they merit also for others who cling to them.

Thus Lot benefitted simply because he remained in Avraham's company.

The [Midrash Tanchuma Buber Ed.](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Bereshit.21.1?lang=bi) notes how this sense of 'clinging' can be both for the positive and the negative. In the case of Lot he benefited due to being in the presence of a tzaddik:

> ואשריהם לצדיקים ולדובקיהם
>
> Fortunate are the tzaddikim and those who cling to them.

The Sefer HaYashar phrases this concept in another way:

> וגם לוט בן הרן אחי אברם היה לו מקנה כבד צאן ובקר ואהלים, כי הטיב ה׳ לו בעבור אברם
>
> And also Lot, the son of Haran, brother of Avram had many livestock, sheep, cattle and tent, because Hashem did good to him for the sake of Avram.